# Stored Procedure Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am afraid my terminology has hindered me from finding the results I am looking for on the internet.  Anyhow, I have a fairly complex stored procedure that I need to pass several variables to.  Instead of entering these variables several time through the stored procedure, is there a way to define a variable at the beginning of the procedure, and reference that variable throughout the procedure?
For example

> IDNumber = 1075, 1050, 1025

Instead of having to use the where clause several time throughout the procedure,

> WHERE IDNumber = 1075 AND IDNumber = 1050 AND IDNumber = 1025

is there a way for me to define those integers in a single variable, and pass the variable through the stored procedure?

Sorry for any confusion that accompanies this questions, as SQL is very new to me.  Thank you for your time and help.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: `WHERE IDNumber = 1075 AND IDNumber = 1050 AND IDNumber = 1025` will of course never be true. Assuming you meant `OR` then a TVP and `IN` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you want to pass in a table valued parameter to your stored proc.  Give this article a read:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

Basically you will define the type:

```
CREATE TYPE myType AS TABLE
(                     
       [myId] int NULL
)
```

Then create a stored proc that accepts that type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
(
      @TableVariable myType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
...
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight and let you know how it goes.  Thanks Abe!